# Unable to remove scroll in kendowindow

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

everyone
I have a popup that opened when click button from another popup. When the popup open it has scroll bar that I don't expect it appear.

```
var win = $("#q-exp-add-edit-window").kendoWindow({
    draggable: false,
    visible: false,
    modal: true,
    //position: {
    //    top: 5,
    //    left: 8
    //},
    resizable: false,
}).data("kendoWindow");
//Set the Window Title
win.title("Entry Notes");
//Set the Window Width & Height
$("#q-exp-add-edit-window").css("width", "870");
$("#q-exp-add-edit-window").css("height", "460");
$("#q-exp-add-edit-window").html("");
win.refresh({
    url: ExpensesEditGrid.urlAddEditNote + params,
    iframe: true
});
//Center & Open the Window
win.center();
win.open();
```

Here is image:
[image]

Many thanks for help .

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the inner table height and width,

so that only inner table will fit and get scrolls inside model.

check the model height and width (or try to assign)

and change the following lines, less than models size.

$("#q-exp-add-edit-window").css("width", "870");

$("#q-exp-add-edit-window").css("height", "460");